# recursive method that checks if a string is palindrome in java

Tags: java

**the input**: "mnkknm" where n=0
**the output**: flag is always equal 1 while it should be equal 3
and it returns -1 
what is the problem ?
note : palindrome means for example if the Reverse of malayalam is also
malayalam then its palindrome
another note : i should write the code recursive as it's a homework

```
public static int PalindromeCheck(String x , int n) 
{

int flag =0;
if (n+1 !=x.length()/2)
{
char s = x.charAt(n);
char y = x.charAt(x.length()-1-n);
if (s==y)
{    flag++;
System.out.println(flag); // i write it to check the value of the flag
}

return  flag+PalindromeCheck(x,n+1) ;
}

if (flag==x.length()/2)
{
return 1;}
else{
return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why you need a recursive method for this? It's as simple as to split the string by half, then take the second half, reverse it and compare.

Comment: @Victor Or just iterate the first half, and test that each character matches the corresponding index (offset from the length) on the right hand side.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch or just iterate the first half of chars,  XOR-them, iterate the second half, XOR-them and compare! as fast as binary comparison!

Comment: @Victor AFAIK `XOR` would not work - does is consider order? (`"abab"` is not a palindrome) | lot of values will create same XOR value (e.g.  `'a' ^ 'g' == 'b' ^ d' == 'c' ^ 'e'`)

Comment: Or just reverse the string and check if it's equal to the original. Though best to compare without case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method please

```
public static boolean isPal(String s)
{
    if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1)) {

        return isPal(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please use *brackets* for `if` statements even if it's just one line.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would create a helped method with that recursive signature (the public function should just take a `String`). And we can test for `null` and the empty string as special cases there. Like,

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String x) {
    if (x == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (x.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    return isPalindrome(x, 0);
}
```

Then your current method seems close, but you want to compare `n` with a less than operator to the half of the length of `x`. Then test that the character matches on the right hand side (offset by `n` from `x.length()` but we need a `-1` because of zero based indexing). Also, the method should return a `boolean` (and I fixed the name). Like

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(String x, int n) {
    if (n < x.length() / 2) {
        if (x.charAt(n) != x.charAt(x.length() - n - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
        return isPalindrome(x, n + 1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd first do 2 or 3 quick checks :

1. if first character fail to match the last. that's a huge time saver without having to reverse anything, esp when input is really long
2. then ask it to locate any character that *isn't* the same as the first. if not, the string already is a nonstop-chain of that same character, then it must be a palindrome.
3. (optional one) if input is REALLY REALLY long, quick check on distribution of components of just that same first character - by definition of a palindrome,

if length is even then # of occurrences of that char *must* also be even.

if length is odd, then it should be even unless the exactly-center character is also that same one, otherwise you'll know the distribution is already not-balanced between left and right, then what's the point of reversing it when u can return false at this point and save time.

if both passes, then do what others have suggested : reverse the right-side half and check if it lines up with left-most index position (0 or 1 depending on which langauge). The reversal part doesn't have to do any of these small checks. just reverse it at high speed.